# How to have autocomplete search using a large JSON file as data source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to build an autocomplete search bar, using a JSON large file containing millions of rows as source.

To have better performance, it is not desired to have Ajax requests to a PHP script making %like% requests to a Database.

I started playing around with JQuery to achieve it but I can't get the JSON function to work.

What are some ways to improve the code below to get better performance when dealing with a large json file?

Thank you very much!

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Search</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input />
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is the javascript, not working properly:

```
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        if (item.name != currentCategory) {
          ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-name'>" + item.name + "</li>");
          currentCategory = item.name;
        }
        that._renderItemData(ul, item);
      });
    }
  });

  $("input").catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "data.json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          term: request.term
        },
        success: function(data) {
          var cat_data = $.map(data, function(item) {
            return {
              name: item.name
            };
          });
          $("#searchfield").catcomplete({
            delay: 0,
            source: cat_data,
            minlength: 0
          });
        }
      });
    },
    minlength: 0
  });
});
```

Here is the JSON data:

```
[{
    "unit":12345,
    "name":"Car Batteries",
    "type":"HardGood",
    "price":0.50,
    "category":[
        {"id":"1","name":"Automobile"},
        {"id":"2","name":"Batteries"}]}
{
    "unit":2345,
    "name":"Soap",
    "type":"Hygiene",
    "price":1.00,
    "category":[
        {"id":"3","name":"Hygiene"},
        {"id":"4","name":"Bathroom"}]}
{
    "unit":56573,
    "name":"Camera",
    "type":"Photography",
    "price":700.50,
    "category":[
        {"id":"6","name":"Photography"},
        {"id":"7","name":"Gadgets"}]}
{
    "unit":94893,
    "name":"iPhone Cable",
    "type":"Cables",
    "price":0.50,
    "category":[
        {"id":"19","name":"Cables"},
        {"id":"20","name":"Mobile"}]}]
```

Comment: *"using a JSON large file containing millions of rows"* - You want to use a database.

Comment: how big is that JSON file? I mean in MB? And how long does it take to load and parse that file?

Comment: Maybe you can increase minLength (like start searching after typing 2-3 chars)?

Comment: `To have better performance, it is not desired to have Ajax requests` - depends on the definition of performance...

Comment: Hey @Thomas, thank you for the help! the file has close to 37 MB, do you think it should be loaded and parsed?

Comment: @Tomalak thanks for the tip! which DB do you recommend?

Comment: *Any* database will be better than a single JSON file with a million entries. Take whatever you have available and know how to operate.